# Creating an outline (box) within a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have stored values within my 2d vector, and made a series of loops and if statements to outline the vector black. How would I modify this to produce a thicker outline?

Here is what I have

```
int NumberOfRows = 49;
int NumberOfColumns = 36;
for (int k = 0; k < x; k++) 
{
    for (double i = results[k][1]; i < NumberOfRows + results[k][1]; i++) 
    {
        for (double j = results[k][2]; j < NumberOfColumns + results[k][2]; j++) 
        {
            if ((i == results[k][1]) || (i == results[k][1] + 48)) {
                a.matrix[i][j] = 1.00;
            }
            else 
            {
                if ((j == results[k][2]) || (j == results[k][2] + 35))
                    a.matrix[i][j] = 1.00;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `1.00` to `2.00` without knowing more its difficult to provide a meaningful answer, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: in c++ vectors have no outline box, nor is "black" somehow defined. You have to explain what your code does, and provide a [mcve] (eg at least include missing declarations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
       if (i - results[k][1] < 2 || i - results[k][1] > NumberOfRows - 2) {
            a.matrix[i][j] = 1.00;
       }
       else if (j - results[k][2] < 2 || j - results[k][2]  > NumberOfColumns - 2)) {
            a.matrix[i][j] = 1.00;
       }
```

where `2` is the desired width.

So this works by subtracting the coordinate from the left edge, `i - results[k][1]`. If that's `< 2` then we're near the left edge, or if that's `> NumberOfRows - 2` then we're near the right edge. Similar process for the top and bottom edges.